# How to make code shorter instead of using 50 useStates and handleChange for each one of the states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const [selectedImage, setImage] = useState(null);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  const [Custom1, setCustom1] = useState("");

  const [Custom2, setCustom2] = useState("");

  const [Custom3, setCustom3] = useState("");

  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  };

  const handeTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handeNumberChange = (e) => {
    setNumber(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCustom1Change = (e) => {
    setCustom1(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCustom2Change = (e) => {
    setCustom2(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCustom3Change = (e) => {
    setCustom3(e.target.value);
  };

  const renderPlaceholder = (value, placeholder) => {
    return value ? value : placeholder;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container rowthem">
      <div className="container mt-lg-5 leftcon">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={handleNameChange}
        />
```

Hello , iam making reactjs cv builder project , but i recognized that its illogical to write the code like this and there must be a shorter and cleaner way that i dont know about , i would appreciate any help of any kind , Thanks . github repo :https://github.com/abdhazouri00/cv

Comment: You can learn to use a form library like https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: Or manage _objects_ in state rather than individual values.

Comment: You can write functions inline

Answer (score 3):

There are various third-party "form" hooks for doing this sort of thing, so you might search for one of those.

Otherwise, the [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#examples-objects) shows almost exactly this situation, as an example of when it would be reasonable to put an object in state and update individual parts of it rather than multiple discrete state elements. But their example still has individual functions for each input, which may not be useful in your situation. Instead, you can use the `name` property of the form field and a single handler. Here's the React documentation example updated to do that:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

function Example() {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        firstName: "Barbara",
        lastName: "Hepworth",
        email: "bhepworth@sculpture.com",
    });

    const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
        setForm((form) => ({
            ...form,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    }, []);

    return (
        <form>
            <label>
                First name:
                <input
                    name="firstName"
                    value={form.firstName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Last name:
                <input
                    name="lastName"
                    value={form.lastName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:
                <input
                    name="email"
                    value={form.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <p>
                {form.firstName} {form.lastName} ({form.email})
            </p>
        </form>
    );
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You could go even further and generate the form fields from the object (you'd add some labelling information) rather than having to write out each field in the code. That can be helpful, or can be an over-abstraction depending on the situation.